# Combining lxfonts with any other mathfont (LateX Beamer)

Tags: beamer, fonts

I have a question about LateX-Beamer.
So i like the font Lxfont. I include it with \usepackage{lxfonts}.

The problem is that I don’t like the lxfont in the Equation-Field. There I would like to have the „normal“ font.

How can I combine these two?

I tried it with \setmathfont{Asana Math}, but the vectors aren’t shown and also \usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif} doesn’t work.